# QT5 RemoteObjects Q_GADGET as PROP

Tags: qt5, qtremoteobjects

I am trying to define a complex structure (practically a POD) as a property in a REP file. The structure is defined already as Q_GADGET in a separate header file.
When I try to instantiate the replica the system crashes complaining that
it is unable to create a certain type (and in the log then comes three completely bogus (e.g. too high) type id numbers)

Is it possible to define structures as properties in the QT5 Remote Object
world? If yes how?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It appears my "naive" operator<< implementation was wrong. I simply <<-ed all the members one after the other into the stream, which caused some issues.
However using the

```
inline QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const my::api::User & value) {
    QtRemoteObjects::copyStoredProperties(&value, stream);
    return stream;
}

inline QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& stream, my::api::User & value) {
    QtRemoteObjects::copyStoredProperties(stream, &value);
    return stream;
}
```

"ethalon" solution (generated my the REPC compiler for PODs) works just fine.